# c++ convert from long to float weird error

Tags: c++, casting, window

```
        POINT p;
        RECT rec;

        ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rec);
        LONG windowWidth = rec.right, windowHeight = rec.bottom;

        ::GetCursorPos(&p);//get position on screen
        ::ScreenToClient(hWnd,&p);//convert POINT to position in window

        // 2d vector math
        float x=0.0f,y=0.0f; // vector
        x= static_cast<float>(p.x - (windowWidth>>1)); // problem...
        y= static_cast<float>(p.y - (windowHeight>>1));

        char buf[100];
        sprintf_s(buf, "x: %d, y: %d\n", x,y); // create string to print
        OutputDebugStringA(buf); // print to debut window
```

when i print x and y to the console it give me crazy numbers. it seems that casting long to float is losing some data, but why? there shouldnt be any problems with it.

it prints:
x: 0, y: 1080795136

Comment: What do you expect `windowWidth >> 1` to do exactly?

Comment: divide the windowWidth by 2

Comment: Which it does not! This is true for integer types, NOT for floating point types. Read about IEEE 754.

Comment: `windowWidth >> 1` is definitely not suggested, you may not get `windowWidth / 2`. just be conventional and divide it by 2 like everyone else would.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have reasonable values in p.y and windowHeight? Next make sure that (windowHeight>>1) is reasonable.

Comment: yes windowWidth was originaly int, sorry about that! and yes the problem was the %d

Comment: @fge: windowWidth has type LONG and even a positive value. But I'd also require a change to /2 on a review

Comment: @BalogPal this is not the matter here. An IEEE 754 32bit floating point number has quite a different format from an IEEE 754 64bit floating point number: the mantissa, for one, does not have the same length.

Comment: @fge: I lost you. We're talking about `windowWidth >> 1` expression where windowWidth is LONG. How floaring point and IEEE enters the picture in the first place? Or was the code edited since the comment?

Comment: @BalogPal because of the conversion to float -- unless I really misunderstand what `static_cast<float>` does.

Comment: The conversion happens after that expression exaluated. static_cast converts the value, if it is representable you get the exact same thing. Here we deal with screen coordinates so values under 10k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 sprintf_s(buf, "x: %d, y: %d\n", x,y);
```

should be

```
 sprintf_s(buf, "x: %f, y: %f\n", x,y);
```

since `x` and `y` are `float` type, not integers.

Comment: to piggy-back off this answer, `float` has a different binary format than `int` and `long`. A value of `4.3f` may look like `-242343` in a binary perspective

Answer (score 3):

If you use %d format and pass a float (that is actually passed as double), no wonder you get garbage. You could get way worse.  Try %f format, or convert to the int expected by %d.

Answer (score 3):

Just modify to

```
sprintf_s(buf, "x: %f, y: %f\n", x,y);
```

because you are using floats

Comment: damn I am the fourth in like 4 mins

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because you're using %d in your sprintf_s call? Try using %f instead and see if that's the issue.